# How to approximate the shape of a human face

Tags: geometry

I am developing an Android application and the task is to check whether the user face is within the head shape. I am able to get facial landmark points (like nose, eyes etc) and have to check if they are within the shape.

How can I approximate the shape (***without ears***) good enough to successfully check the above? Using a simple oval seems not accurate enough.

[image]

**EDIT**: I suppose the most exact solution would be to define a set of points on the shape edges and interpolate the function with splines, with analytical approach the accuracy won't be so good.

Answer (score 3):

A rather convenient parametric representation of a head is:

$$\tag{1}x=a \cos(t) (1+c \sin(t)), \ \ \ y=b \sin(t)$$

(modified ellipse) with $a=3, b=4$ and $c=0.15$. See plot below.

All you have to do now is to convert $(1)$ into a cartesian representation, by eliminating parameter $t$ (essentially by using $\cos(t)^2+\sin(t)^2=1$):

$$\tag{2}\dfrac{(x/a)^2}{(1+cy/b)^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Thus a point $(x,y)$ is inside the "head" iff the following inequality is verified:

$$\tag{2}\dfrac{(x/a)^2}{(1+cy/b)^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}<1$$

Edit: I obtained a slightly flatter head by adding in $(1)$ an extra $c \sin(t)^2$ inside the parenthesis, i.e. taking $x=3 \cos(t)(1+c \sin(t)+c \sin(t)^2)$.

[image]